# My c output always 0

Tags: c

When i run this c program to calculate BMI, the output i get is always 0
can i know whats the problem? i am able to get the value of w and h but it seems bmi keeps returning 0 as the result

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float w, h, bmi;
    printf("please enter your weight in kg");
    scanf("%d", &w);
    printf("please enter your height in m");
    scanf("%d", &h);

    bmi = (w/(h*h));
    printf("Your BMI is %d\n", bmi);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `"%d"` -----> `"%f"`  ...Take a look at [format specifiers](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: `scanf("%d", &w);` --> `scanf("%f", &w);` and likewise.

Comment: Also, if you use the wrong specifiers, `scanf` and `printf` will exhibit undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &w);
```

should be

```
scanf("%f", &w);
```

You are using a wrong format specifier to scan a float. You should use `%f`

Answer (score 0):

Your format specifier for scanf are wrong.

As you can see on [the Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

> **d**
>
> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int.

So you need a different one:

> **f**
>
> Matches an optionally signed floating-point number; the next pointer must be a pointer to float.

Then your code should be, at least:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    float w, h, bmi;
    printf("please enter your weight in kg: ");
    scanf("%f", &w);
    printf("please enter your height in m: ");
    scanf("%f", &h);

    bmi = (w/(h*h));
    printf("Your BMI is %f\n", bmi);
    return 0;

}
```

You can also take look at `scanf` return value

> **Return Value**
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

That in other words means: check the return value. If you expect a single `float`, `scanf` must return 1 if valid input is input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float w = 0;
    float h = 0;
    float bmi = 0;
    
    printf("please enter your weight in kg: ");
    
    if (scanf("%f", &w) == 1)
    {
        printf("please enter your height in m: ");
        if (scanf("%f", &h) == 1)
        {
            if (h!=0)
            {
                bmi = (w/(h*h));
                printf("Your BMI is %f\n", bmi);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Height cannot be 0!\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error inputing height!\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error inputing weight!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Last thing, as you can see, is that you must check that entered height is `!= 0`.

Comment: don;t forget the print.......